# Why doesn't my SQL insert into work?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I know questions like this exist all over, but I can't see what's wrong with my code. The DB works and I run an update query just fine earlier on in the code.

Query 1:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `login_history` (`memberid`, `ip`, `host`, `location`, `status`, `date`) VALUES ('".$login."', '".$ip."', '".$details->hostname."', '".$loc."', 'success', NOW()");
```

Query 2:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `login_history` (`memberid`, `ip`, `host`, `location`, `status`, `date`) VALUES ('".$login."', '".$ip."', '".$details->hostname."', '".$loc."', 'failure', NOW()");
```

Here is an echo of the string as requested:

```
INSERT INTO `login_history` (`memberid`, `ip`, `host`, `location`, `status`, `date`) VALUES ('AAL', '**.60.**.**', 'c-174-**-**-**.hsd1.**.comcast.net', 'Town, US', 'success', NOW()
```

Comment: You should echo out your SQL, I would be money that one of the variables is empty and therefore spoiling your insert statement.

Comment: Prepared statements! You won't regret it :) http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Would also recommend testing out your echo using phpmyadmin

Comment: What error do you get in your console?

Comment: @Fluffeh Echoing the query? That does nothing

Comment: @JoshBjelovuk No errors

Comment: you should post the actual query string here. If I had to guess I would say one of those variables has an apostraphe in it. That would terminate the value and cause a syntax error - prepared statements as jason said. Escaping values is pretty important

Comment: There are no errors when you echo mysqli_error (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)? Perhaps the script is never executing. Have you tried using mysqli_query instead? You may need to depending on what version of PHP you're using.

Comment: @KaiQing INSERT INTO `login_history` (`memberid`, `ip`, `host`, `location`, `status`, `date`) VALUES ('AAL', '**.60.**.**', 'c-174-**-**-**.hsd1.**.comcast.net', 'Town, US', 'success', NOW() I replaced numbers with *s for my security

Comment: @user3325134 Yes I have. I just put the string after variables go through in the main post

Comment: If you have a Foreign Key in memberid maybe it is constraining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the final closing `)`. Also use prepared statements. Much cleaner and safer. Here is a quick example of what a Prepared Statement would look like (adapted [from here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)) (you wold also need to make other changes to your PHP script to start using them)

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `login_history` (`memberid`, `ip`, `host`, `location`, `status`, `date`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())")
$stmt->bind_param('sssss', $login, $ip, $details->hostname, $loc, 'failure');
$stmt->execute()
```